# how to get the information about the music track playing in the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get the information about the music track playing on the iPhone.
And my application is a separated one which is running on the iPhone

Am I able to get that information?

Answer (score 2):

check out the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: thanks.
I found something what I would need here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingMediaPlayback/UsingMediaPlayback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH100-SW7

I want to am I able to get the information about the now playing track which will be played by a another application?